# Inicia o serviço do banco com uma função

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma função que assim que iniciar o software, eu possa iniciar o serviço do banco de dados caso o mesmo esteja desligado.
to usando java com swing, netbeans e MySQL

desde já grato.

Answer (score 0):

Mano se o mysql estiver desligado não tem como vc iniciar o seu banco, vc pode configurar na sua classe Main para abrir o mysql assim q executar o seu projeto usando o "Process". exemplo:

```
Process cal = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");//abri calculadora
```

vc pode cria um process para abrir o mysql